# 3.5 mm microphone plugs- person with Parkinson's

Tags: microphone, adapters

I wonder if any of you can help me.

I am attempting to help a lady with Parkinson's who needs to use a voice amplifier because of her very quiet voice. She has this amplifier https://voiceaid.net/, but the microphones headsets etc supplied are not suitable for her. The 3.5 mm plugs of the microphones supplied have one black band (mono- TS, I understand).

I found a better style of over the ear microphone for her https://www.thomann.de/gb/albrecht_nackenbuegelmikrofon_for_att400.htm

The 3.5 mm plug of the new microphone have 3 black bands on them. TRRS, I think.  I did read around before I ordered and from what I could understand (obviously wrongly) it should  have been compatible with the amplifier. But it is not. They fit in the socket but the amplifier does not work with the new microphone.

Before I do something drastic (ie mount the original microphone onto the new head set with superglue), is there an adapter that I could use that could convert 3 black bands to one? I know I am not using the technical terms but I hope you will excuse!!

I have googled around extensively but I cannot seem to find an appropriate adapter. Maybe it does not or cannot exist, or maybe I am looking in the wrong place.

Thanks very much in advance, for the help to the ignorant!!! I am in the UK